# using select statement to invoke data and check if code column has Test value

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

using select statement to invoke data and check if code column has Test value using VBScript

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>

<%
Function Select()  

Dim SQL,Test

SQL = " SELECT code, name, value FROM fruits "

If (strSQL = strSQL & "code = 'Test' ") then
MsgBox("Hello world")
End If

End Function   
%>
```

Comment: What are you trying to validate, the response from the Sql query ?

Comment: if code column contains the data named Test than show msg box hello world

Comment: The MsgBox() function will cause the box to pop up on the web **server**, not in the client's web browser. This may work for you in testing, but only because your server and browser are on the same machine.

Comment: Excellent point @JoelCoehoorn. But i believe he is debugging his code. Just an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like;

```
 Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'db connection
 Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'Record set

 Conn.Open "dsn=YourDNS" 'open the connection

 RS.open "SELECT code, name, value FROM fruits WHERE code = 'Test'" ,Conn

 if not RS.eof then
    if RS.fields("Code").value = "Test" then
        MsgBox("Hello World")
    end if
 end if
```

Comment: Since you are already filtering in the SQL, no need to check, enough to know if the recordset is not EOF.